# ghostscript: convert PDF into GRAY preserving pure Black for text

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, color-conversion

I need to convert RGB PDF into a CMYK/GRAY PDF.
I use the following command line:

```
    gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
       -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
       -dPDFSETTINGS="/prepress" \
       \
       -sColorConversionStrategy=$2 \
       -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=$2 \
       -dProcessColorModel=$3 \
       \
       -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
       -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
       -dMonoImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
       \
       -dDownsampleColorImages=false \
       -dDownsampleGrayImages=false \
       -dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
```

where $3 is /DeviceGray or DeviceCMYK and
$2 is CMYK or Gray.

Unfortunately the text is in the gray mode only 91% black.
In the CMYK mode the text is 100% black.
How can I set the text to 100% black in the gray mode?

I use GS 9.26 and no special ICC profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert to Gray while preserving text as Black, it will be converted to Gray as well.

You could provide an ICC prfile which converts R=G=B=0 into a CIE colour which, when mapped back through through the Gray ICC profile results in 100% gray, which is the same (obviously) as black. I'm afraid its up to you to source suitable ICC profiles.

With the current version of Ghostscript you don't need to (and shouldn#'t) set the ProcessColorModel when using ColorConversionStrategy, it'll be set for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I don't understand: I have two different CMYK-files both with text 100% K. One file is converted to 100% gray and the other to 91%.    (The percent values I got from Adobe Acrobat.) The same is true for RGB-files. Is there a magic parameter in the input files?

Comment: Maybe there is a ICC-profile in the different files which I could deactivate? I would like to prevent developing a ICC profile, I don't have the ability.

Comment: There must be 'some' difference between the input files. Very possibly they contain their own ICC profiles. Or they are not really in CMYK, just because Acrobat gives you CMYK values doesn't mean the input file expressed the colour that way. Without looking at the files I can't tell you though.

Comment: Maybe I could go an other way. is it possible to convert a cmyk-page to a cmyk-page with a certain k and cmy equal 0?

Comment: Fundamentally, no, not without creating custom ICC profiles. **All** the colour management in the pdfwrite device is done through ICC profiles.